# Run x86 Virtual Machine in a AIX Standalone Host

Tags: aix

I need to run a Linux Debian x86_64 system/guest in a IBM POWER7 (big-endian) AIX 7.2 standalone (no HMC) host. Is there another solution besides try to experimently install QEMU from source code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation: No.

AIX 7.X supports WPAR (workload partitions, more like 'Containers' aka the 'jail' concept) not LPAR (Logical Partitions).

Perhaps a different way of comparing:

WPAR <> Docker (AIX based)
LPAR <> VM (can be AIX, Linux (debian, ubuntu, SLES, RHEL, Centos, Fedora, etc.), IBM i, or VIOS)

In short, you will need - at least an HMC, and I would recommend VIOS as well.

Or, a second disk, and install Debian on that disk, and boot from that disk - classic bare metal.

Comment: I think it's possible do that only with VIOS and IVM. Am I correct? Thank you very  much.

Comment: Ivm is only in vios 2.x, and that would work fine. I own a power6 and use vios2 plus ivm. I have installed 4 different linux, no 5, distros. not much lately, power6 is a bit old for newest distros.

Comment: Can IVM run x86 systems (inside POWER7 host)?

Comment: Yes. With ivm you create an lpar, better partition, assign some storage, virtual ethernet, 0.1 cpu uncapped, and 1g ram is probably enough for install.

Comment: Yes, not x86, only linux for ppc. My mistake.

Comment: Thank you Michael.